# Symfony - Updating OneToOne doctrine relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have Form that should update a OneToOne Relation between User and a CoverPhoto

**User**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\CompanyCoverPhoto", mappedBy="company", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $companyCoverPhoto;
```

**CoverPhoto**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="companyCoverPhoto", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $company;
```

**Controller**

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // holds the submitted values iN MeM
        $a = $form->getData();
        /** @var UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
        $uploadedFile = $form['companyCoverPhoto']->getData();
        if ($uploadedFile) {
            $newFilename = $up->uploadCoverImage($uploadedFile, $a->getFilename());
            $a->setFilename($newFilename);
        }
        // save edits to the database
        $m->persist($a);
        $m->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('show_home');
    }
```

Error that I'm having

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\CompanyCoverPhoto", "instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile" given at property path "companyCoverPhoto".

If I do a Form just to update the Cover Photo, it works for new Entries but not for updates
Any help at all is much apreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your form builder look like? It seems like you're adding a field `companyCoverPhoto` as a file upload when it should be an entity field that references CompanyCoverPhoto.

Comment: it's supposed to be a field where you upload a photo

Comment: Yeah, but your Entity expects a CompanyCoverPhoto there, so when the form bundle tries to set an uploaded file, it'll reject it. You might have to add a form type for the CompanyCoverPhoto Entity that contains the code for uploading. Look at VichUploaderBundle, you can most likely use that and reduce the code you need to write yourself.

Comment: it works perfectly when the field is in the same Entity ( User ) but now with OneToOne relation is not :( / I have createad a separate Form just for that, but can't figure out how to make doctrine update the relation instead of Inserting a new Entry everytime someone uploads a photo